# Why does a trait on a reference raise "cannot borrow as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable" when a trait on an object does not?

Tags: rust, traits

Consider a function

```rust
fn clear_non_empty<T>(collection: &mut Vec<T>) {
    if !collection.is_empty() {
        collection.clear()
    }
}
```

it compiles just fine, and if I try to generalize it for some collection

```rust
trait IsEmpty {
    fn is_empty(&self) -> bool;
}

trait Clear {
    fn clear(&mut self);
}

fn clear_non_empty<'a, Collection: Clear + IsEmpty>(collection: &'a mut Collection) {
    if !collection.is_empty() {
        collection.clear()
    }
}
```

I also have no problems. But if I change traits to

```rust
trait IsEmpty {
    fn is_empty(self) -> bool;
}

trait Clear {
    fn clear(self);
}

fn clear_non_empty<'a, Collection>(collection: &'a mut Collection)
where
    &'a mut Collection: Clear,
    &'a Collection: IsEmpty,
{
    if !collection.is_empty() {
        collection.clear()
    }
}
```

I'm getting

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*collection` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/lib.rs:15:9
   |
9  | fn clear_non_empty<'a, Collection>(collection: &'a mut Collection)
   |                    -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
14 |     if !collection.is_empty() {
   |         ---------------------
   |         |
   |         immutable borrow occurs here
   |         argument requires that `*collection` is borrowed for `'a`
15 |         collection.clear()
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0502`.
```

which I do not understand, why traits with methods accepting references to `self` work and traits implemented for references with methods accepting `self` do not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the way you've declared the lifetime you want to use:

```rust
fn clear_non_empty<'a, Collection>(collection: &'a mut Collection)
where
    &'a mut Collection: Clear,
    &'a Collection: IsEmpty,
{
    if !collection.is_empty() {
        collection.clear()
    }
}
```

You've given `clear_non_empty` a *lifetime parameter*. This means that it's a lifetime *the caller* can pick, and also that it outlives the entire `clear_non_empty` function call (because in nearly all cases that's a practical requirement for the function to be able to *use* the lifetime). But that's not what you need — you need *two* lifetimes (one for calling `is_empty()` and one for calling `clear()`) that *do not overlap,* so that they do not conflict.

Lifetime parameters can't do this, but you don't actually need a lifetime parameter. What `clear_non_empty` needs to know is: “if I take a borrow of `Collection`, will it implement `Clear`?” And Rust in fact has a syntax for this (having the somewhat esoteric name of “higher-rank trait bounds”, or HRTB):

```rust
fn clear_non_empty<Collection>(collection: &mut Collection)
where
    for<'a> &'a mut Collection: Clear,
    for<'b> &'b Collection: IsEmpty,
{
    if !collection.is_empty() {
        collection.clear()
    }
}
```

(Syntax note: `for<'a>` is introducing a lifetime for the following bound only, so each bound *could* use the same name; I wrote `for<'b>` just to highlight that they *are* distinct.)

Notice that the `collection` parameter no longer has a lifetime — that's also important, because when we call `collection.clear()` we're not passing *the reference we got* to it, we're passing an implicit *reborrow* with a shorter lifetime, so that it doesn't conflict with the borrow for `is_empty`. The new lifetime annotations accurately reflect what we're doing with `collection`, rather than requiring longer lifetimes.

The reason you don't have to worry about this when writing traits like `trait Clear { fn clear(&mut self); }` is because the lifetime quantification — "for any lifetime 'a, we can clear `&'a mut Self`" — is implicit in the *function signature* of `Clear::clear`, which could be written explicitly as `fn clear<'a>(&'a mut self);`. it is normal that functions from a trait can be called with lifetimes shorter than any constraint on the implementor of the trait.

Answer (score 0):

I thought this could perhaps be solved by using separate lifetimes for `IsEmpty` and `Clear`, like so:

```rust
trait IsEmpty {
    fn is_empty(self) -> bool;
}

trait Clear {
    fn clear(self);
}

fn clear_non_empty<'is_empty, 'clear, Collection>(collection: &'clear mut Collection)
where
    Collection: 'clear + 'is_empty,
    &'clear mut Collection: Clear,
    &'is_empty Collection: IsEmpty,
{
    if !collection.is_empty() {
        collection.clear()
    }
}
```

However this still runs into:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:15:9
   |
9  | fn clear_non_empty<'is_empty, 'clear, Collection>(collection: &'clear mut Collection)
   |                    ---------  ------ lifetime `'clear` defined here
   |                    |
   |                    lifetime `'is_empty` defined here
...
15 |     if !collection.is_empty() {
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ argument requires that `'clear` must outlive `'is_empty`
   |
   = help: consider adding the following bound: `'clear: 'is_empty`
```

Here we see that the compiler is convinced that `'clear` must outlive `'is_empty`, while instead we require that these lifetimes do not overlap. But if these lifetimes do not overlap, then how can we turn our mutable reference into an immutable one for the duration of the call to `is_empty`?

It could be we are running into a limitation of the borrow checker, but let's give it some help and try to separate `'clear` and `is_empty` a bit more:

```rust
trait IsEmpty {
    fn is_empty(self) -> bool;
}

trait Clear {
    fn clear(self);
}

fn clear_non_empty<'is_empty, 'clear, 'input, Collection>(collection: &'input mut Collection)
where
    'input: 'clear + 'is_empty,
    &'clear mut Collection: Clear,
    &'is_empty Collection: IsEmpty,
{
    if !collection.is_empty() {
        collection.clear()
    }
}
```

It does not help:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*collection` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/lib.rs:16:9
   |
9  | fn clear_non_empty<'is_empty, 'clear, 'input, Collection>(collection: &'input mut Collection)
   |                    --------- lifetime `'is_empty` defined here
...
15 |     if !collection.is_empty() {
   |         ---------------------
   |         |
   |         immutable borrow occurs here
   |         argument requires that `*collection` is borrowed for `'is_empty`
16 |         collection.clear()
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
```

At this point I am pretty confident that this is indeed a borrow checker limitation, although I am not sure whether this is a bug or a feature.

If I were you I would open an [issue on the Rust repository](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues) to get some expert help.